# How to login Stack Overflow using other account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

How to login Stack Overflow using other account?

I login with linjuming@gmail.com account of Stack Overflow open id. when I logout and want to login with using my other Stack Overflow open id mingfish@qq.com. The site allways auto login using my current account (linjuming@gmail.com), How to switch between different Stack Overflow accounts ?

Comment: **Remove your real email ids from the question if you want to keep it private.**

Comment: Is that showing real email in post is forbidden?

Comment: No. Read my comment again. I told **If** you want to keep it private.

Comment: @hims056 Not a duplicate. I think he's asking how to log in to a different account, not change the logins on his current account.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Is he talking about different Stack Overflow accounts?

Comment: yes, I can not change to my other account, the linjuming@gmail.com and mingfish@qq.com are both stackflow open id account , I first login with linjuming@gmail.com, then I logout ,but when click login , it did not display the account input fields ,and derectly login with linjuming@gmail.com